# How to set the title of a Windows console while npm is running?

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, npm

I have started to develop a web application project on my Windows machine, for which I use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), [bower](http://bower.io/), and the [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) HTTP server.

For easier start of the HTTP server, I created the batch file:

```
@echo off
title HTTP Server
npm start
```

`npm start` starts the `http-server`. For that I have the following entry in the `packages.json`:

```
"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1"
```

But when I double click the batch, the title of the opening console window first changes to `npm` and then to `bower`. So it ignores my own title while `npm`/`bower` is running.

Since I have many console windows open, I would like to force the `HTTP server` console window to have my specific title. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Replace in .bat (batch) Line `npm start` by `start "TITLE" "npm start"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the title in your `package.json` file:

```
"start": "title HTTP Server && http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the start of the HTTP server is not my problem. The ``packages.json`` configures the ``start`` section for ``npm start`` with ``"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1"``. But while the HTTP server is running, my window title is just ``bower``, but I want to have it like ``HTTP Server``, so that I can distinguish it better in my task bar.

Comment: @Desty i think you need to give the Title in package.json file.

Comment: That has helped, thanks! Would you like to edit your answer or create a new one, so that I can approve it? What I have now in my ``packages.json`` is: ``"start": "title HTTP Server && http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1"``

Comment: @Desty you can edit my answer way you want but please upvote it.

Comment: Mind that this is just a workaround. package.json preferably should contain commands referencing ONLY npm packages. If you use scripting commands in package.json like TITLE (from cmd) than your command will not run on someone else's machine on bash/linux. Still upvoting because there is no better solution.

Comment: I don't have a `packages.json` (plural), only a `package.json`.  I've tried the above solution in that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 13):

You can set the title in app.js by adding the following line:

```
process.title = "HTTP Server";
```